# Async:return from functions in waterfall method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, async.js

I am calling an a function like this

```
MyService.validate(params,function(err,response){
     //results from validate 
     console.log(response);
})
```

In `Myservice.validate`  there is an async `waterfall` function is doing a 
 validation each validation rules run in single function if any one fails i want to return back

```
//run validations here
validate:function(params,callback){

   async.watefall([

     function (nextValidation){
      if(params.length<8){
         //returns to MyService.validate callback
         return callback({'status':false})
      }
      nextValdation();
     },
     function (finalCallback){

     if(params.name!='foo'){
         //returns to MyService.validate callback
         return callback({'status':false})
      }
      finalCallback();

     }


],function(err,response){
   //all validation rules passed 
   return callback({'status':true})
})

}
```

But if one of the validation fails the return is not working ie

`return callback({'status':false})` never fired

```
if(params.length<8){ 
         //never fired
         return callback({'status':false})
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you are trying to call callback from first function in waterfall. Instead call its callback i.e. nextvalidation with err set. I think you need to read little more about async.waterfall. For a hint use validate function like this -

```
var async = require('async');

var validate=function(params,callback){

   async.waterfall([

     function (nextValidation){
      if(params.length<8){
         //returns to MyService.validate callback
         nextValidation({'status':false})
      }
      else nextValidation();
     },
     function (nextValidation){

     if(params.name!='foo'){
         //returns to MyService.validate callback
         nextValidation({'status':"random"})
      }
      else nextValidation();

     }


],function(err,response){
   //all validation rules passed
   if(err) return callback(err);
   else return callback({'status':true})
})

}

validate("1234",function(err,response){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("all set");
})
```

Comment: I've already tried this But this approach runs all the validation functions even if first function fails

Comment: edited the answer, its working for me. Change the stub for different inputs and try it. Let me know if any problem is there.